# How can i send cross domain ajax request with JSON response?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

Guys,

I want to send a cross domain ajax request(http://dict.qq.com/dict?q=language), but the server only provides JSON(**Not JSONP**) response, is there anyway to make the request ?

Here's what i've did:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://dict.qq.com/dict?q=language",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    type:'get',
    processData:false,
    crossDomain:true,
    contentType:"application/json",
    success:result
});

function result(data){console.log(data);}
```

The response is :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

The server also needs to be configured to allow cross domain requests, something like:

```
  Http.Response.current().accessControl("*", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from doing so. 
If you have access to the other server you can attempt to change the http headers sent to circumvent this. Here's a tutorial for using [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) to achieve this.

If you have no control over the remote server perhaps you can try using a server-side proxy such as [this one](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)